# Indents and spacings starting a line are ignored in parbox

Tags: spacing, line, parbox

When inside a `\parbox`, indents and spacings (like `\indent`, `\quad`, `\hspace{}`, etc...) are ignored when starting a line.  For example, this code:

```
\parbox[t]{10cm}{
    \indent indent does not work \\
    hi \hspace{2em} this hspace works \\
    \hspace{2em} this hspace does not work \\
    \quad quad doesnt work but \quad this one does
}
```

produces:

[image: Indents and spacings eaten]

Is there a setting to have leading indents/spacers working inside a parbox?

Comment: you can set `\parindent` back to its default value (eg 15pt) the behaviour of `\hspace` and `\quad` though is not affected by the parbox, such spaces are always discarded at the beginning of a line whether or not there is a parbox.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `\parbox`.  \\ is not the way to start a new line. Use a blank line.  See [When to use \par and when \\, \newline, or blank lines](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/82664)

Comment: Use `\hspace*{...}` for start-of-line spacing.

Comment: @AlanMunn Not using \\ and instead using \par or a blank line solved it!  My university has been using \\ in all of their provided documents, so I guess I've been taught a bad practice.  Thank you!  Please make an answer and I'll accept it!

Comment: Sorry I got excited that `\quad` and `\hspace` was working so I didn't realize `\indent` was not working.  I did not modify `\parindent`, nor does doing `\setlength{\parindent}{15pt}` result in anything.  Though oddly enough, doing a double indent `\indent\indent` works.  Is there a way to `\indent` without doing double?